# My cells won't display but I'm not getting error messages or breakpoints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I customized my cells a little bit, and my `UICollectionView` displays (in light green, as I set it in Interface Builder) but my cells won't display.  I don't have any breakpoints or error messages of any kind.

viewcontroller.h

```
@interface CollectionViewController : UIViewController
 <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
{
    IBOutlet UICollectionView * myCollectionView;
    NSMutableArray *Items;
}
@end
```

viewcontroller.m

```
#import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "CustomizedCell.h"

@interface CollectionViewController ()


@implementation CollectionViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     Items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [myCollectionView setDataSource:self];
    [myCollectionView setDelegate:self];

    [Items addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bittenCookie.jpg"]];
    [Items addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cookie.jpg"]];

    [myCollectionView registerClass:[CustomizedCell class]     forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"customizedCell"];
     [myCollectionView reloadData];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
    return Items.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UIImage * image;
     image = Items[indexPath.row];
    CustomizedCell * cell = (CustomizedCell *)[collectionView     dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"customizedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     [cell LoadCell:image];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

The class for customizing cells

```
@interface CustomizedCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView * imageInCustomizedCell;
}
-(void)LoadCell: (UIImage *)image;    

@end

//
//  CustomizedCell.m
//  ChangeUp
//

#import "CustomizedCell.h" 

@implementation CustomizedCell 

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)LoadCell: (UIImage *)image
{
     [imageInCustomizedCell setImage:image];
}

@end
```

Comment: Objective-C best practice is to lowercase the first letters of variables and methods:  "`loadCell`" instead of "`LoadCell`", "`items`" instead of "`Items`".  Also, you should set breakpoints and get comfortable with Xcode's debugger so you can step through "`cellForItemAtIndexPath`" and make sure everything is not nil.

Comment: Tag your question with "objective-c" and "ios".

Comment: Where are you setting the frame on `imageInCustomizedCell`? In InterfaceBuilder?